# Is the ideal (x,2) maximal in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am just wondering if that is the case in the ring $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ because in class we showed that it is maximal in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$

I believe that (x,2) is also not principal in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** $\ 2$ is a unit (invertible) in $\Bbb Q,$ and any ideal containing a unit $u$ contains $\,u u^{-1}\! = 1$.

Note also that $\Bbb Q[x]$ is a PID, because it is Euclidean, using the polynomial division algorithm.

Comment: Are you saying that (x,2) is $\mathbb{Q}[x]$? Would it be alright if I said that $1 = 0\times x + 2 \times \frac{1}{2}$? I am trying to learn all this new material, a confirmation would be helpful

Comment: Yes, to both. $\,r\in R,\ 1\in I\:\Rightarrow\: r\cdot 1 = r\in I\,$ so $I$ contains every $\,r\in R,\,$ i.e. if an ideal contains $u$ then it contains all multiples of $u$. When $u=1,$ every element is a multiple of $1$.